# open link in new tab

Tags: 2010

I am on my sharepoint 2010 personal site, using the my links web part.

I have a dozen links to other sharepoint sites and regular sites.  I would like to be able to click on the link and have it open in a new tab.

I have tried adding target=_blank and it doesn't work. I know I can either hold the ctl key then left click or right click and chose new tab.  Was looking for more of something along the lines of target = _blank, so I don't have to do the extra key strokes.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to leverage jquery, with a specific selector, to achieve the desired results of opening in a new tab.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.enter-selector a').attr('target', '_blank');
});</script>
```